# Ipad Simulator can't connect to internet or local web server

Tags: xcode, ipad, cordova

I am trying to setup phonegap 2.7 on xcode 4.6.2 using jquery mobile. I can't seem to get my ap to access the internet or access a local web server I'm running using ajax.

I've set the config.xml already to support

But it seems the issue is the ipad simulator can't access the internet, I've tried to open safari and type a url in the addressbar but don't get a response. I have wifi connection and can't figure out how to enable the network in the ipad simulator.

Please help